# for j=1:rowdata.size, data{j} = rowdata.get(j-1) end

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have object of linkedList called `rowdata(java.util.LinkedList)` and I want to convert into cell Array of MATLAB. Any suggestion except follow?

```
for j=1:rowdata.size,
        data{j} = rowdata.get(j-1)              
end
```

As rowdata is having too much data, it will print every iterate of loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer of how to do it but a very basic suggestion for Matlab use.

In Matlab, if you dont want an output to be printed in the command line, you should end the line with a semicolon.

Example:

```
a=3+4

a =

     7

a=3+4;

"Nothing!"
```

So you can suppress all outputs by

```
for j=1:rowdata.size,
        data{j} = rowdata.get(j-1);              
end
```

This wont change the behaviour of your code, but it will avoid annoying command line prints.